# How to compare dates from previous rows and update entries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

I've been pulling my hair out in an attempt to find a way of updating some entries by comparing the dates from previous rows.

Here's a sample of the date stored in the table I am willing to update:

```
ContractId  PartnerId   DocumentState   DealsDate   ActualCloseDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------
119577922   1450216     38              2016-04-21  2017-08-01
222138372   1450216     38              2017-11-22  2019-04-01
223328932   1450216     38              2018-07-30  2018-11-19
224263667   1450216     38              2019-01-15  2019-04-19
225286013   1450216     38              2019-06-21  2019-07-19
225704493   1450216     38              2019-08-30  2019-12-11
```

The aim is to change the `DocumentState` to 36 for all the `ContractId`s for which the `ActualCloseDate` of any of the entries prior to it is bigger than its `DealsDate`.

The output should look like this:

```
ContractId  PartnerId   DocumentState   DealsDate   ActualCloseDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------     
119577922   1450216     38              2016-04-21  2017-08-01
222138372   1450216     38              2017-11-22  2019-04-01
223328932   1450216     36              2018-07-30  2018-11-19
224263667   1450216     36              2019-01-15  2019-04-19
225286013   1450216     38              2019-06-21  2019-07-19
225704493   1450216     38              2019-08-30  2019-12-11
```

Below is the code for inserting the data into a temporary table.

```
create table #Test 
(
     ContractId int, 
     PartnerId int, 
     DocumentState int, 
     DeasDate datetime, 
     ActualCloseDate datetime
)

insert into #Test (ContractId, PartnerId, DocumentState, DealsDate, ActualCloseDate) values (119577922, 1450216, 38, '2016-04-21', 2017-08-01')
insert into #Test (ContractId, PartnerId, DocumentState, DealsDate, ActualCloseDate) values (222138372, 1450216, 38, '2017-11-22', 2019-04-01')
insert into #Test (ContractId, PartnerId, DocumentState, DealsDate, ActualCloseDate) values (223328932, 1450216, 38, '2018-07-30', 2018-11-19')
insert into #Test (ContractId, PartnerId, DocumentState, DealsDate, ActualCloseDate) values (224263667, 1450216, 38, '2019-01-15', 2019-04-19')
insert into #Test (ContractId, PartnerId, DocumentState, DealsDate, ActualCloseDate) values (225286013, 1450216, 38, '2019-06-21', 2019-07-19')
insert into #Test (ContractId, PartnerId, DocumentState, DealsDate, ActualCloseDate) values (225704493, 1450216, 38, '2019-08-30', 2019-12-11')
```

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an updatable CTE does what you want:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(ActualCloseDate) over (partition by PartnerId
                                        order by dealsDate
                                        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                       ) as prev_max_acd
      from #test t
     )
update toupdate
     set documentstate = 36
     where prev_max_acd > dealsdate;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec506bf4caecbc4e0c2446dcc057be3e) is a db<>fiddle

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
update Test set DocumentState = 36
where exists (
    select * from Test inrTest
    where inrTest.ContractId < Test.ContractId
    and inrTest.ActualCloseDate > Test.DealsDate
)
```

if the order is not on "ContractId", then just change the contract id condition to the column you want to order with